# Certain sensitive PHP files overwritten with garbage. Hard-drive fault? How could this happen? Should I be worried?

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.4, hard-drive, php5

I was trying to upgrade a Prestashop store in a local copy in my machine. Running XAMPP under Windows 7. I put that on hold for a while while I browsed some websites with Firefox. When I came back and reloaded Prestashop, I got a very **strange output**, something similar to this:

```
 GLorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController; 7Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/TextFieldInplaceEditor; &Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Scene; 'Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget; CLorg/netbeans/modules/visual/action/TextFieldInplaceEditorProvider; ^Ljava/util/EnumSet; bLjava/lang/Object;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider; (Ljava/awt/Dimension;)V ()Ljava/awt/Font; (F)Ljava/awt/Font; (Ljava/awt/Font;)V !(Ljava/awt/event/FocusListener;)V (Ljava/awt/event/KeyListener;)V ()Ljava/lang/String; (Ljava/lang/String;)V '(Ljavax/swing/event/DocumentListener;)V ()Ljavax/swing/text/Document; (()Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Scene; *(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;)Z ;(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;)Ljava/lang/String; ;)V ›(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)Ljava/util/EnumSet; ›(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;Ljavax/swing/JTextField;)Ljava/util/EnumSet; °(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)Ljava/awt/Rectangle; °(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;Ljavax/swing/JTextField;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)Ljava/awt/Rectangle; æ(Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/action/InplaceEditorProvider$EditorController;Lorg/netbeans/api/visual/widget/Widget;Ljavax/swing/JTextField;)Ljava/util/EnumSet;  R # S  T  W  Y       4  9    6 _  `  a 5 b    c 1 c 
 d 2 d  e  f  g 0 g  h  i  j  k 7 l  n 
 r % s $ t  w  y   L {     L |     L }     L ~     L 
 A …
 B 
 B ˆ
 C ‚
 D ƒ
 D †
 D ‰
 D Š
 D ‹
 D Œ
 D 
 D Ž
 D 
 D ’
 J €
 J „
 J ‡
 K “
 L ˜
 L ™
 L š
 L ›
 L œ
 M —
 N —
 O — E  E ‘ I ” I • I – Code EditorController ExpansionDirection InnerClasses LineNumberTable LocalVariableTable LocalVariableTypeTable    Signature 
SourceFile 
StackMapTable #TextFieldInplaceEditorProvider.java 1 L C  F    Y     T  È    ]  # S     R     W      m  Á   k     *· ¥*+µ ¡*,µ Ÿ±    Å       F  G   H  I Æ         8 \       Y      T  Ç         ]  È    u  
 r  Á   ú     Y*´ ¡,¹ ¾ š °» DY*´ ¡,¹ ¿ · ®N-¶ ¦,¶ ³:¶ °9—ž !¶ ²:¶ £k¶ ¤:-¶ ¨-°    Ê   
 þ G D J Å   .    L 
 M  N ! O % P + Q 2 R 9 S @ T Q U W W Æ   H  @   P    Y 8 \     Y  X    Y ; [  ! 8  V  + . 3 Z  2 ' @    % s  Á   À     X-» AY@· ¢¶ §*» MY*+· ¹µ ž*» NY*+· ºµ *» OY*+· »µ  -*´ ž¶ «-*´ ¶ ©-¶ ¯*´  ¹ ¼ -¶ ¦±    Å   &       [  \  j ) o 6 | > } F ~ S  W € Æ   *    X 8 \     X  X
```

Which I don't know, looks like some **memory dump out of Netbeans**' memory?

When I troubleshot the issue, seems like **several .php files** under the prestashop folder **had been rewritten** with similar garbage. Namely:

- prestashop/classes/Page.php
- prestashop/classes/PaymentCC.php/PaymentCC.php
- prestashop/classes/PaymentModule.php/PaymentModule.php

I got this out of a diff between the original prestashop folder and the shop's.

The thing is, I wasn't manipulating any of those files and I made no requests to the webserver in that time and I noticed no strange behaviour from Windows. I had Netbeans 8.1 open under Oracle's JVM jdk1.8-91.

Since those are kind of some sensitive files it made me worried.

So my **question** is, how could this garbage made its way to be **written in the hard drive**? Could I troubleshoot this any further with Windows? Should I be worried that somehow this was an attempt to **tamper** with those files?

After that, I rebooted the machine and performed a chkdsk. This is its output:

```
Comprobando el sistema de archivos en D:
El tipo del sistema de archivos es NTFS.
La etiqueta de volumen es Nuevo vol.
```

Uno de los discos necesita ser comprobado para ver coherencias.
Se puede cancelar la comprobación de disco, pero se recomienda
que continúe.
Windows comprobará ahora el disco.

CHKDSK está comprobando archivos (etapa 1 de 3)...
  760576 registros de archivos procesados.                                Comprobación de archivos completada.
  660 registros de archivos grandes procesados.                          0 registros de archivos no válidos procesados.                       0 registros de EA procesados.                                              0 registros de análisis procesados.                                CHKDSK está comprobando índices (etapa 2 de 3)...
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0x8477a es incorrecto.
de d3 14 be 75 e3 6d 71 72 30 0c 2d 2d 20 af 9a  ....u.mqr0.-- ..
28 c7 e9 ac b3 a2 ef 53 61 a1 7b 9b 64 04 8f ab  (......Sa.{.d...
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 542586.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0x8477a es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 542586.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01  .........&6.[...
aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01 aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01  .&6.[....&6.[...
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 542586.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0x8478d es incorrecto.
8f dd e5 ff 68 cd bd 62 cc 37 f9 88 41 bf 56 f2  ....h..b.7..A.V.
41 8e 88 b4 11 2a c0 de 28 aa 5a 87 49 af c6 19  A....*..(.Z.I...
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 542605.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0x8478d es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 542605.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01  .........&6.[...
aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01 aa 26 36 06 5b 8e d1 01  .&6.[....&6.[...
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 542605.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3785 es incorrecto.
6e 2f 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63  n/project/Projec
74 43 6f 6e 66 69 67 75 72 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 24  tConfigurations$
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 735109.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3785 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 735109.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 735109.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3bd2 es incorrecto.
54 61 62 6c 65 01 00 12 4c 6f 63 61 6c 56 61 72  Table...LocalVar
69 61 62 6c 65 54 61 62 6c 65 01 00 15 52 65 73  iableTable...Res
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736210.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3bd2 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736210.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736210.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3bd4 es incorrecto.
6d 61 67 65 2f 49 6d 61 67 65 4f 62 73 65 72 76  mage/ImageObserv
65 72 3b 29 49 01 00 2c 28 4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 61  er;)I..,(Ljava/a
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736212.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3bd4 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736212.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736212.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3be7 es incorrecto.
34 58 d6 d3 c1 46 04 74 ac dd ea 4b d3 ac 15 3e  4X...F.t...K...>
4e ad 8c 88 2c 59 a4 c5 f0 59 f2 02 6e 6c 09 14  N...,Y...Y..nl..
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736231.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3be7 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736231.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736231.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3be9 es incorrecto.
b6 04 f4 47 e4 2a 7c a7 ef 1b 3e c7 2d cd c8 f9  ...G.*|...>.-...
8a 99 68 83 b5 01 17 3d a9 c8 c9 da 5d f7 b6 12  ..h....=....]...
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736233.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3be9 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736233.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736233.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3cfa es incorrecto.
65 57 1b 71 23 30 91 14 40 24 95 27 72 7d eb 94  eW.q#0..@$.'r}..
d1 31 30 8d ee 36 7b a5 e5 d4 11 6d 8d 57 7d bb  .10..6{....m.W}.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736506.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3cfa es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736506.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736506.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3cfc es incorrecto.
eb 83 89 cc 59 26 96 f1 56 7a 34 6e 46 36 b5 30  ....Y&..Vz4nF6.0
fc df c4 fe 64 d4 b3 01 a5 ec 66 df 0d ca 76 f4  ....d.....f...v.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736508.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3cfc es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736508.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736508.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3d02 es incorrecto.
ba 74 47 b1 c4 7e 9f 2b 88 83 b3 4d 0d 20 a8 ec  .tG..~.+...M. ..
90 5b 6b d2 5c 78 92 aa 1c c8 63 54 77 49 6d 18  .[k.\x....cTwIm.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736514.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb3d02 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 736514.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 43 cb 34 42 e3 34 d2 01  ........C.4B.4..
80 6d 22 87 a5 e5 d1 01 2c 96 38 42 e3 34 d2 01  .m".....,.8B.4..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 736514.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb3d0f es incorrecto.
75 78 e3 b5 8e a9 c3 69 bb ab 77 aa 14 b3 f0 55  ux.....i..w....U
28 99 3d c0 4a ee 59 3c 54 0e c5 4a 91 84 8c 8e  (.=.J.Y.y.....y,.d..@k
0f 77 b3 ef 02 21 cb 43 c3 bb 01 74 19 f9 4b ca  .w...!.C...t..K.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 738813.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb45fd es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 738813.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 738813.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb46f9 es incorrecto.
8b c8 59 60 c1 c9 c5 4b ba 2e b3 23 dd cf 26 a4  ..Y`...K...#..&.
a1 0f 1e d7 f6 4e cf e4 2e db 49 74 3d 55 f9 5d  .....N....It=U.]
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739065.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb46f9 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739065.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739065.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb477b es incorrecto.
da fb 9b 3a b0 3e e6 4e 4e 0f 1a 93 de eb 3d 5a  ...:.>.NN.....=Z
87 c4 5c 93 ec 58 d4 35 b1 52 41 6d 1b 11 2b b4  ..\..X.5.RAm..+.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739195.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb477b es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739195.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739195.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb478c es incorrecto.
e4 f9 28 6d 84 69 b3 60 79 3c 10 3c fe b6 6e e1  ..(m.i.`y<.<..n.
af 3f 5d 36 05 d7 e4 a5 69 0a f8 fc a6 ee 44 2c  .?]6....i.....D,
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739212.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb478c es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739212.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739212.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb480d es incorrecto.
fc 0c 0a 61 c8 e1 b8 49 10 5f 22 50 f6 ac 7a 02  ...a...I."P..z.
07 c2 16 63 d4 35 1d 9d 30 26 6e 89 89 7f 55 64  ...c.5..0&n...Ud
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739341.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb480d es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739341.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739341.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb481d es incorrecto.
4f e4 8e 6e eb 68 6f 0b dd b8 bf 73 eb be 8e 4e  O..n.ho....s...N
28 cd 9d cc 3c da 16 0a b7 02 0b 26 cc dd d3 d9  (...<......&....
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739357.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb481d es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739357.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739357.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo  0xb4a54 es incorrecto.
b9 ed 8c 0c d9 6f 26 f0 a2 96 ac 6d f4 ef e0 e3  .....o&....m....
91 e2 12 af aa 3b 0e 5e f4 10 21 17 10 47 73 36  .....;.^..!..Gs6
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739924.
El mapa de bits $I30 en el archivo 0xb4a54 es incorrecto.
Corrigiendo error en índice $I30 para archivo 739924.
El indicador descendente de la entrada de índice con longitud 0x18 no es
válido.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ec 8e 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  .............D..
13 d7 f8 29 af 44 d2 01 0c dd 11 81 b0 44 d2 01  ...).D.......D..
Ordenando índice $I30 en archivo 739924.
La firma de encabezado del sector múltiple VCN 0x0 del índice $I30
en el archivo

Which I guess just looks like a NTFS / hard drive failure? Seems like a big coincidence.

Should I take any more actions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `chkdsk` output shows that there is some filesystem corruption. There can be many reasons for this like memory corruption, unexpected power loss etc.

That corruption is likely cause for the stuff you see in the files.

Comment: Check the drive's SMART status to see if there are any pending/reallocated/uncorrectable sectors. This will indicate whether or not the corruption was caused by mechanical failure (in which case, run a backup and replace the drive ASAP), or a software glitch/cosmic rays/etc.